# Pause Mediaelement in Windowos phone 8 if user navigates to the other app or homescreen

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I had developed application which plays videos using MediaElement with remote url. Everything works fine videos are also playing nicely.

**But the problem I am facing is if user is playing video and user touches windows button on phone. Then my app goes to background and home screen is displayed. now on home screen user touches back button. My app is brought to foreground and video starts loading from beginning. Is there anyway by which I can pause mediaelement so that when user comes back to my app video gets resumed.**

One more thing is I can not user MediaLauncher since I want to log some events when user interacts with mediacontrols such as play/pause.

Kindly requesting you all to  guide me in this scenario.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

you can resume your application via **ActivationPolicy** attribute to the **DefaultTask** element inActivationPolicy attribute to the DefaultTask element in WMAppManifest.xml and set the value to “Resume”. For this task, you need to edit the app manifest directly instead of using the manifest editor. To do this, right-click WMAppManifest.xml, click Open with, and then choose XML (Text) Editor.

For Resume can be enabled for XAML apps, Direct3D apps, and Direct3D with XAML apps. The following examples show how the DefaultTask element will look for a XAML app and for a Direct3D app.

```
<DefaultTask Name="_default" NavigationPage="MainPage.xaml" ActivationPolicy="Resume"/>

<DefaultTask Name="_default" ImagePath="PhoneDirect3DApp1.exe" ImageParams=""  ActivationPolicy="Resume"/>
```

[app resume for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj735579%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_Resumeandrefreshthepageonthetopofthebackstack)

[app resume backstack sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Fast-app-resume-backstack-f16baaa6)

If this will not help you than you can manual paly and stop your video pleyer like bellow code

**XAML**

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="0.90*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="0.10*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <SSME:SmoothStreamingMediaElement x:Name="video" Grid.Row="0" />
        <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1">

            <Button   x:Name="PlayButton" Width="150" Click="PlayButton_Click"  Loaded="PlayButton_Loaded"/>
            <Button   x:Name="StopButton" Content="Stop" Width="100" Click="StopButton_Click" />

            <TextBlock x:Name="status"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="currentBitrate"/>

        </StackPanel>

        <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
        <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0"></Grid>
    </Grid>
```

**C# code:**

```
 public partial class VIdeoStraming : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        string VideoUrl,StreamingUrl;
        public VIdeoStraming()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
            VideoUrl = this.NavigationContext.QueryString["parameter0"];
            string Manifest="/Manifest";
            StreamingUrl = VideoUrl + Manifest;                     
        }

        private void PlayButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //Monitor the state of the content to determine the right action to take on this button being clicked
            //and then change the text to reflect the next action
            switch (video.CurrentState)
            {
                case SmoothStreamingMediaElementState.Playing:
                    video.Pause();
                    PlayButton.Content = "Play";
                    break;
                case SmoothStreamingMediaElementState.Stopped:
                case SmoothStreamingMediaElementState.Paused:
                    video.Play();
                    PlayButton.Content = "Pause";
                    break;
            }
        }

        private void PlayButton_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            switch (video.AutoPlay)
            {
                case false:
                    PlayButton.Content = "Play";
                    break;
                case true:
                    PlayButton.Content = "Pause";
                    break;
            }
        }

        private void StopButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            //This should simply stop the playback

                video.Stop();
                //We should also reflect the chang on the play button
                PlayButton.Content = "Play";

        }

        private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            video.CurrentStateChanged += new RoutedEventHandler(video_CurrentStateChanged);
            video.PlaybackTrackChanged += new EventHandler<Microsoft.Web.Media.SmoothStreaming.TrackChangedEventArgs>(video_PlaybackTrackChanged);
            //video.SmoothStreamingSource = new Uri("http://64.120.251.114:1945/live/sharedobjects/layoutvideo/mp4:1311370468970.MP4/Manifest");
            video.SmoothStreamingSource = new Uri(StreamingUrl);
            video.ManifestReady += new EventHandler<EventArgs>(video_ManifestReady);
        }

        //when use in mobile device
        void video_ManifestReady(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SmoothStreamingMediaElement ssme = sender as SmoothStreamingMediaElement;

            if (ssme == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            // Select the highest band of tracks which all have the same resolution.
            // maxMobileBitrate depends on the encoding settings
            const ulong maxMobileBitrate = 1000000;
            foreach (SegmentInfo segment in ssme.ManifestInfo.Segments)
            {
                foreach (StreamInfo streamInfo in segment.AvailableStreams)
                {
                    if (MediaStreamType.Video == streamInfo.Type)
                    {
                        List<TrackInfo> widestBand = new List<TrackInfo>();
                        List<TrackInfo> currentBand = new List<TrackInfo>();
                        ulong lastHeight = 0;
                        ulong lastWidth = 0;
                        ulong index = 0;

                        foreach (TrackInfo track in streamInfo.AvailableTracks)
                        {
                            index += 1;

                            string strMaxWidth;
                            string strMaxHeight;
                            // If can't find width/height, choose only the top bitrate.
                            ulong ulMaxWidth = index;
                            // If can't find width/height, choose only the top bitrate.
                            ulong ulMaxHeight = index;
                            // V2 manifests require "MaxWidth", while v1 manifests used "Width".
                            if (track.Attributes.TryGetValue("MaxWidth", out strMaxWidth) ||
                                track.Attributes.TryGetValue("Width", out strMaxWidth))
                            {
                                ulong.TryParse(strMaxWidth, out ulMaxWidth);
                            }

                            if (track.Attributes.TryGetValue("MaxHeight", out strMaxHeight) ||
                                track.Attributes.TryGetValue("Height", out strMaxHeight))
                            {
                                ulong.TryParse(strMaxHeight, out ulMaxHeight);
                            }

                            if (ulMaxWidth != lastWidth ||
                                ulMaxHeight != lastHeight)
                            {
                                // Current band is now finished, check if it is the widest.
                                // If same size, current band preferred over previous
                                // widest, because it will be of higher bitrate.
                                if (currentBand.Count >= widestBand.Count)
                                {
                                    //  A new widest band:
                                    widestBand = currentBand;
                                    currentBand = new List<TrackInfo>();
                                }
                            }

                            if (track.Bitrate > maxMobileBitrate)
                            {
                                break;
                            }

                            // Current track always gets added to current band.
                            currentBand.Add(track);
                            lastWidth = ulMaxWidth;
                            lastHeight = ulMaxHeight;
                        }

                        if (0 == widestBand.Count &&
                            0 == currentBand.Count)
                        {
                            // Lowest bitrate band is > maxMobileBitrate.
                            widestBand.Add(streamInfo.AvailableTracks[0]);
                        }
                        else if (currentBand.Count >= widestBand.Count)
                        {
                            // Need to check the last band which was constructed.
                            Debug.Assert(currentBand.Count > 0);
                            widestBand = currentBand; // Winner by default.
                        }

                        Debug.Assert(widestBand.Count >= 1);
                        streamInfo.RestrictTracks(widestBand);
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        void video_PlaybackTrackChanged(object sender, Microsoft.Web.Media.SmoothStreaming.TrackChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            currentBitrate.Text = e.NewTrack.Bitrate.ToString();
        }

        void video_CurrentStateChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            status.Text = video.CurrentState.ToString();
        }

        private void imghdrleft_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            NavigationService.GoBack();
        }

        private void imghdrright_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Planet41VIew/Settings.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi Manish I did following code changes 
<DefaultTask Name="_default" NavigationPage="SplashScreenPage.xaml" ActivationPolicy="Resume"/>
Still its not working. Should I add following line instead of above line <DefaultTask Name="_default" NavigationPage="FullScreenVideoPage.xaml" ActivationPolicy="Resume"/>

Comment: how it possible bcos this artical is given by msdn and i also use this thing,it will work fine in my aplication

Comment: plese read this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj735579%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_Resumeandrefreshthepageonthetopofthebackstack

Comment: What is SSME since I am using mediaelement.My Main issue how do i pause mediaelement when user moves away from my app.i want to start video from the point where it was left.

Comment: i just give you demo of how to manually pose video and SSME is video pleyer like medea eliment.

Comment: And best way is Resume app but i dont know why it is not working in your application